# How do i convert MERN web app to desktop app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, electron

I have created a simple billing web application using Node, Express, React and MongoDB
However i want to convert it into a Desktop application for local machines.

I know it is possible using electron, but i don't know how to do it.
Can anyone help me or provide with necessary resource?

Comment: any solution ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) to get start a new project with react and electron.
Your build HTML file will act as the view file for your `electron` app.Which should be build by `react-scripts`.Use express server in separate file and use the server.
Handle requests just like you do in a MERN app.you only need to set the view to the bundled HTML file.

Comment: how to run  express and react at the same time